# What is the Rest Assured proper JsonPath get() format for selecting the value of a field within an array of JSON objects

Tags: java, json, rest-assured, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using rest assured to make an API post call and getting a response back in the body. I then need to take this response and select specific field values and store them as strings to be compared later against other string objects. I wrote jsonpath just fine to get the top level field values (like id, status, type, country, etc.) but when i have to get inside one of the objects within the json array that is returned I cant get the format correctly for the get() method.

Here is an example of the Json that is returned:

```
{
  "id": "ABC123",
  "status": "NEW",
  "type": "PERSONAL",
  "country": "United States",
  "totalBalances": {},
  "availableBalances": {},
  "fields": [
    {
      "fieldType": "mobilephone",
      "value": "14216904425",
      "fieldId": "personalMobileNumber"
    },
    {
      "fieldType": "email",
      "value": "user12345@work.com",
      "fieldId": "personalEmail"
    },
    {
      "fieldType": "STRING",
      "value": "John Doe",
      "fieldId": "individualName"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the json path I was trying to get formatted to fit into the get() method but i get an Illegal Argument exception everytime (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid JSON expression) i try to make it work. Basically I need to identify the right object in the array and grab the proper field value. In this case that is the fieldId field and i want the field "value" value (John Doe) so that I can save that to a String object:

```
JsonPath pathToAccountName = response.jsonPath();
String accountName = pathToAccountName.get("fields[?(@.fieldId=='individualName')].value")
```

I used https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ for the getting the VALID json path:

```
$.fields[?(@.fieldId=='individualName')].value
```

But I tried everything to convert it into something the get() method will accept and no luck. Scouring all the the posts here and the rest assured technical docs hasnt helped either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rest Assured uses Groovy's Gpath. So your query could look like this:

```
JsonPath pathToAccountName = response.jsonPath();
String value = jsonPath.getString("fields.find { it.fieldId == 'individualName' }.value");
```

Here you can find some examples (it's about processing XML, but also applicable to JSON):
http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html

Comment: This solution worked for me, I did not realize rest assured was looking for a Gson path rather than a Json path. Thanks for clarifying this!

Comment: Thanks. This one was helpful

Answer (score -1):

I need to know how to get this output -

JSON DOC - `{ "status": "E000", "customerId": "VjAxI2VhNzg5ZmJlLWIyNjAtNGZlOS1iZDNkLTdjMmU1MjA2ZmVhZA", "merchantId": "1", "cards": [ { "cardType": "DEBIT", "cardIssuer": "AXIS", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "CREDIT", "cardIssuer": "ICICI Bank", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "CREDIT", "cardIssuer": "HDFC Bank", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "CREDIT", "cardIssuer": "ICICI Bank", "cardBrand": "VISA", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "DEBIT", "cardIssuer": "Punjab National Bank", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "CREDIT", "cardIssuer": "ICICI Bank", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": null, "expired": null, "cardMigrationStatus": "DONE", "tur": null, "category": null } ], "status_mssg": null }`

I want this output -
`[ { "cardType": "DEBIT", "cardIssuer": "AXIS", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "CREDIT", "cardIssuer": "ICICI Bank", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "CREDIT", "cardIssuer": "HDFC Bank", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null }, { "cardType": "DEBIT", "cardIssuer": "Punjab National Bank", "cardBrand": "MASTERCARD", "nickName": "", "expired": "false", "cardMigrationStatus": "OPEN", "tur": null, "category": null } ]`

I am using this - jsonPathValidator.getString("$.cards[?(@.cardMigrationStatus == 'OPEN' && @.cardBrand == 'MASTERCARD')]");

but not getting the output.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31106379)